# mvc5 How to write popup Partialpage using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I popup a Partial View when I click on Button. Here I'm using Jquery

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnPartial">CallPartilal</button>
```

This partial calling Working fine

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/_Partial1.cshtml")
```

Comment: Return partial page html from action and place that html in model popup div and you can open that model $("#id").modal('show');

Comment: @BhubanShrestha could u please give any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('#someButton').click( function() {
           $.ajax({
              url: '/controller/action',
              data: ...some data for action...,
              dataType: 'html',
              success: function(data) {
                 $('#partial').html(data);
                 $('#partial').modal('show');
              }
           });
       });
   });
</script>


public ActionResult Action(...)
{
  //var model = ...//If partial view requires model

  return PartialView( "PartialViewLocation");
 //Return PartialView("PartialViewLocation", model)
}
```

Comment: $('#partial').modal('show');   in this code #partial is what